# code block not showing up in my answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In my long answer to [this question](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/music-theory-frequencies-related-to-playing-a-note-on-guitar/6945#comment9590_6945) 
the code-block I used to ensure alignment of my test is not displaying
on my browser.  Is this affecting other users? Is there some way I need to modify my entry?

Comment: It could be a jTab quirk.

Answer (score 3):

I put the block in a `<pre></pre>` 
 section; which I guess is the way to avoid having jTab process any "code samples" on this site.

Comment: Indeed; that's the accepted workaround for jTab wonkyness.