# How to turn off auto guitar-chord-chart in posts?

Tags: support

I tried to draw an ascii art Circle of 5ths like this

[image: ascii circle of 5ths]

It previews fine while I'm writing the post, but after posting it the notes get transformed into a guitar chord diagrams, like:

[image: auto chord charts]

How do I disable this for my post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [code block not showing up in my answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/code-block-not-showing-up-in-my-answer)

Answer (score 5):

This is due to jtab which will be active in code blocks use `<pre></pre>` to delineate your code blocks to fix it like so:

```
<pre>
          C | G
        F   |   D
      B♭    |     A
      E♭    |     E
        A♭  |   B
          D♭| G♭
</pre>
```

...which produces:

```
          C | G
        F   |   D
      B♭    |     A
      E♭    |     E
        A♭  |   B
          D♭| G♭
```

Comment: @Shog9 since you've dropped by, any chance we can revisit [this feature request](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240/guitar-tab-plugin-jtab-should-be-active-only-in-questions-tagged-guitar)?

Comment: I'll toss it on the ol' TODO list, @Dom.