# How to use preformatted text *without* abcjs rendering it as abc music

Tags: support

When I put text like "Bm" into preformatted text it gets rendered by ABC JS as chord symbols.

Is there a way to override this?

Comment: See https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2764/how-to-turn-off-auto-guitar-chord-chart-in-posts/2765#2765